# protobuf-net custom tool inside solution directory?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, protobuf-net, custom-tools

I love that protobuf-net has a custom tool installed along with its installer.

However, my team uses an in-solution folder `lib` directory, under which you can find protobuf-net.

How can I register the custom tool target for this solution/my projects only, without doing any global changes to my VS2010 settings? I'm happy to hack my csproj/sln files as needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Custom tools in VS (i.e. via the item properties) are *insanely* hard coded. I would love it if this was easier to deploy, I really would - then I could deploy it with nuget. However, currently the only way to install a custom tool is with registry hacking, which requires an installer.

I even pestered Phil Haack about it when we were both in Sweden, but: that option doesn't exist. I even looked into the other extension options new in VS2010 (via the extension manager), but I'm pretty sure these *also* don't include custom-tool support.

However! If all you want is to be able to generate the files, then all you *actually* need to do is to execute `protogen`, specifying the `.proto` files to use as input. So if you are happy to change your csproj such that the build launches the `protogen` exe, that will probably suffice.

Note that the `protogen` tool only does code-generation, and any code generated with the v1 version of `protogen` should still work fine if you are referencing the v2 library dll.

Comment: Another component we use in our project, LinqToXSD, does something similar -- see their readme's `Visual Studio integration` section: http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/56601#989005

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar, in order to call protogen without specifically setting that in the project?

Comment: @David no, not that I am aware of. It must either be pre-installed in the IDE, or done independently. Unless you want to volunteer to write the custom build tasks?

Comment: I've never done it before, but I'd be willing to give it a shot. Do you know if the next VS release fixes the above issue before I spend time working on a problem that will be largely irrelevant if it does?

Comment: @David I have not investigated the extension changes in VS vNext; I do not know if this situation changes. As an aside; note that protogen is merely an exe wrapper - the codegen itself is available in library form.

Comment: Thanks Marc. In my case, project A creates a tool that is used by other projects in the solution. It seems that pre-build events on other projects are a more likely solution than dyno-magically installing a custom tool.